# Как подключить библиотеку на c++ к проекту на go?

Tags: dll, golang

Как подключить библиотеку на c++ к проекту на go?

Comment: golang.org/cmd/cgo/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Если у библиотеки на Си++ есть Си API -- то использовать его (API) вместе с `cgo`. Иначе это API придётся писать самому. В среднем случае задача не простая.

## Пример

[Источник](https://www.teddy.ch/c++_library_in_c/)

#### C++ библиотека

Головы

```cpp
#ifndef __MYCLASS_H
#define __MYCLASS_H

class MyClass {
        private:
                int m_i;
        public:
                void int_set(int i);

                int int_get();
};

#endif
```

Тело

```cpp
#include "MyClass.h"
void MyClass::int_set(int i) {
        m_i = i;
}

int MyClass::int_get() {
        return m_i;
}
```

#### Обёртка на Си

Головы

```cpp
#ifndef __MYWRAPPER_H
#define __MYWRAPPER_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct MyClass MyClass; // тип класса

MyClass* newMyClass(); // прототип конструктора

// прототипы публичных методов

void MyClass_int_set(MyClass* v, int i);

int MyClass_int_get(MyClass* v);

void deleteMyClass(MyClass* v); // прототип деструктора

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Тело

```cpp
#include "MyClass.h"
#include "MyWrapper.h"

extern "C" {
        MyClass* newMyClass() {
                return new MyClass(); // вызов конструктора
        }

        void MyClass_int_set(MyClass* v, int i) {
                v->int_set(i); // вызов публичного метода
        }

        int MyClass_int_get(MyClass* v) {
                return v->int_get(); // вызов публичного метода
        }

        void deleteMyClass(MyClass* v) {
                delete v; // вызов деструктора
        }
}
```

В данном примере имеется исходный код библиотеки на Си++ и всё в итоге компилируется Си++ компилятором. Т.е. Обёртка для Си делается на Си++. Обязательно нужно:

- завернуть встроенные функции, такие как `new` и `delete`
- каждому публичному методу класса писать функцию обёртку

В примере нет таких Си++ возможностей как шаблоны, операторы и пр., которые способны увеличить объём работы. Так же, если исходного кода библиотеки нет, то придётся писать промежуточную библиотеку на Си++ с аналогичными обёртками. При это промежуточная библиотека будет вызывать функции целевой.В итоге получится Go->промежуточная библиотека->целевая библиотека.